# How can I get an element with a string regardless if it corresponds to its class or its ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let us consider this function:

```
function validateField(selector) {
    $(selector).on("change, blur", function() {
        // do stuff
    });
}
```

That element could have an id=selector or a class=selector. How can I proceed with such abstraction?

Comment: `#selector, .selector`.

Comment: So can we assume `selector` is a string value of some `id` or `class`?

Comment: Yes, it is a string value of some id or class.

Comment: Unless the selector is prefixed with `#` or `.` this wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply refer to *both* by doing something like this:

```
function validateField(selector) {
    var $selector = $('#'+selector+', .'+selector); // This will reference every class and id with the selector's name
    $selector.on("change, blur", function() {
        // do stuff
    });
}
```

Comment: `var $selector =$('#'+selector+', .'+selector);  $selector.on(......` seems more natural to me here. At least with my code, a variable that starts with `$` is usually a jquery object. +1 though

Comment: No matter how unlikely, this will cause unwanted behavior if classes and IDs overlap.  Check my answer to avoid those conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try something like this, try to see if it's ID first, if it returns 0 as length, try class. But this isn't an good way to do it, maybe you can also try with a flag

```
function validateField(selector) {
   var $selector = $('#' + selector);

   if ($selector.length === 0) {
      $selector = $('.' + selector)
   }

   $selector.on("change, blur", function() {
     // do stuff
   });
}
```

With an flag

```
function validateField(selector, classSelect) {
   var $selector;

   if (classSelect === true) {
      $selector = $('.' + selector)
   } else {
      $selector = $('#' + selector)
   }

   $selector.on("change, blur", function() {
     // do stuff
   });
}
```

Comment: I think you want `$selector.length` instead of `selector.length`

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If OP can change validateField function usage, then it's much better to pass '#adsf' or `.adsf` in the first place and use `$(selector).`

Answer (score 1):

This function will accommodate both ID and class selectors:

```
function validateField(selector, Type) {
    var SelectorString = "";
    if (Type == "ID")
        SelectorString = "#" + selector;
    else if (Type == "Class")
        SelectorString = "." + selector;
    else
        return; // invalid so don't create event handler.

        $(SelectorString).on("change, blur", function() {
            // do stuff
        });
}
```